# Azure DevOps - Calling a PS script from within a PS script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

Can you not call a script from within a script in an Azure PowerShell task?

**Background -**

I have a an Azure Repo with two scripts in it (let's call them *script0* and *script1*). There's no build going on so there's no build pipeline. There's just a release pipeline. The artifact it is picking up from is *Azure Repository Git*. I have just one task in the (release) pipeline and it's the Azure PowerShell task.

In *script0*, which is the main script, I have a for loop, which requires me to run the *script1* (apart from the various other things that goes on in the loop).

For the life of me, I am unable to figure out how I can achieve that. Worst of it, it works locally. Also, everything else works in the loop. I have tried tons of things to fix it, but I will start with just this for now: The error I am being thrown when I run

```bsh
$TeamFoundationCollectionUri$TeamProject/testscript.ps1 $stage $FunctionHosts[$i] (($hashtable | select -First 6).Key[$i]) $ResourceGroupName $location $functionApps $AdminClientSecret $VaultName $JsonFile
```

(Now, mind you - that is part of *script0* - the main script).

Here's the error:

[image]

The blurred area is *script0* and **testscript.ps1** is *script1*

I have tried almost everything

1. Using the Call operator &
2. Using \, /, //
3. Invoke-Expression -Command "<`code here`>"
4. Invoke-Command
5. Also tried powershell.exe -Command <`code here`>

As you can tell, none of these have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by using the Call operator (`&`) before the path where the script resides. So, I did this:

`& $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\$(System.TeamProject)\testscript.ps1 <pass the params here>`

and it worked.

Comment: Did that! Thanks